# No configuration required for ILogger?

Tags: c#, ninject, nlog, ninject-logging

I'm trying out Ninject's Logging extension (v3.0) with NLog (v2.0) and, from what I've read, I'm not supposed to configure anything, the thing is like *auto-magical* and all I need to do is declare a `ILogger` dependency wherever I need one.

I kept the `nlog.config` file I already had, and removed all code that created loggers and instead put `ILogger` in my classes' constructors.

I'm getting an `ActivationException` at the composition root, ...Ninject can't resolve `ILogger`.

What am I missing?

What I have essentially boils down to this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // nothing special here, binds IMyApp to MyApp.
    using (var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectConfig()))
    {
        var app = kernel.Get<IMyApp>(); // MyApp has a ILogger dependency **blows up here**
        app.Run(args);
    }
}
```

This is a console app, for what it's worth... Is the logging extension supposed to work like this?

---

The documentation says:

> make sure you have the kernel load a new Log4NetModule or NLogModule before requesting the type instance

But if I do this:

```
    using (var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NLogModule(), new NinjectConfig()))
    {
        ...
```

...ReSharper doesn't know what `NLogModule` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the nuget package for `Ninject.Extensions.Logging` isn't enough.

You also need to download the nuget package for `Ninject.Extensions.Logging.nlog2`, which contains the `NLogModule` class that's needed to bind the `ILogger` interface.

There's also an available nuget package for log4net logging available.

This:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectConfig())
```

Is all that's required to make everything work - no need to explicitly load a `new NLogModule()`.